# How to move columns to the left in table?

Tags: html, css

I want to move columns to the left and also there should be set a fixed size in between.

Now it looks like this:

[image: 1]

Hopefully I could get this result:

[image: 2]

CSS Code:

```
.table {
    width:100%;
}

.table table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
}

.table td{
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#EFEFEF; }
.table tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }

.table tr:first-child td{
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    text-align:left;
    color:#868686;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* Border line in the middle (first-child) Example: 1 | 2 | 3 */
.table tr:first-child td:not(:last-child) { border-right: 1px solid #868686;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table" >
    <table>
        <tr>
             <td>
               ID#
             </td>
             <td>
               Name
             </td>
             <td>
               Edit
             </td>
              <td>
               Delete
             </td>
       </tr>
       
<tr><td><?php echo $tags_id ?></td><td><?php echo $name ?></td> <td><?php echo "<a href='edit.php?id=$tags_id'>Edit</a>"; ?></td> <td><?php echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$tags_id'>Delete</a>"; ?></td></tr>

       </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that `:not` is not fully supported.

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: table is not a block element. It should be taking up only as much space as its content

Comment: Could you post a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You should know that you can embed images in questions. No need to upload them on another site.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/2gnr7odq/?

Comment: @Amit Yes like this but could you fix first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us what version of HTML you are using, but the following should work in any version.  Add a <colgroup> as the first child of your table element like this:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="20em"/>
    <col width="10em"/>
    <col width="10em"/>
  </colgroup>
</table>
```

This will fix the widths of the columns to a certain number of characters.  If this doesn't work out the way you want it to, try setting a width attribute on the <table> and use percentages in your <col/> widths:

```
<table width="40%">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="50%"/>
    <col width="25%"/>
    <col width="25%"/>
  </colgroup>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.table {
    width:50%;
}
```

This should solve the issue. Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzzcrouf/3/. You can also try this for better styling -
http://jsfiddle.net/xzzcrouf/4/

Comment: I don't want to change width to 50 % only moving columns to left if this is possible?

Comment: It's close, could text be under each label? Now it looks like this with your last jsfiddle: http://i.imgur.com/XGONlj3.png

Comment: thats what the other link does with a better styling - http://jsfiddle.net/xzzcrouf/4/

Comment: I tried this but i get the result shown in the picture above.

Comment: If text in a column is too long the rest will be pushed.

Comment: yes. That's the price you pay. You can't have the best of both worlds. My advice, you shouldn't be looking for extra space on the right.

Comment: You can adjust min-width if you know the max size of the data in your columns if you still want to go with the above approach

Answer (score 0):

You've setup the `width:100%` to your table that means all the column will try to span across all the available width. So you can remove that from your table

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltu71vhb/)

Comment: Yes i know but it should be 100% width and columns should be aligned to left if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2gnr7odq/2/)**

```
.table {
    width:100%;
}
.table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
}
.table tr {
    clear:both;
}
.table tbody td, .table th {
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
}
.table thead tr {
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
}
.table thead tr th {
    color:#868686;
    border-right: 1px solid #868686;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I removed `width:100%` from my table in CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="table" >
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:50px">
            <col style="width:250px">
            <col style="width:180px">
            <col style="width:1500px">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>ID#</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>NAME</td> 
            <td>EDIT</td> 
            <td>DELETE</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kxo5epy7/5/)

Maybe there is a better way but it's displayed as I wanted.

Thanks @pgoetz for sharing the information about **colgroup**.

Comment: Hi - If my response answered your question, mark it as answered so that the next person who comes along with the same question can benefit from this discussion.  Thanks!